# How to substitute the local dependency with external CDN link in Webpack?

Tags: webpack, babylonjs

I am trying to do something like this:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
        babylonjs: "https://preview.babylonjs.com/babylon.js?t=1682926053948",
    }
},
```

Instead of using saved local dependency I want to get the modified version from somewhere else via https and check how project runs with it.

I could copy it locally and use `path.resolve`, but I feel there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Webpack's [Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) feature

> The `externals` configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles.

E.g.

Add the CDN link of `babylon.js` to the HTML template.

`src/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/babylon.js?t=1682926053948"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

`src/index.js`:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('renderCanvas'); // Get the canvas element
const engine = new BABYLON.Engine(canvas, true); // Generate the BABYLON 3D engine
const createScene = function () {
    // Creates a basic Babylon Scene object
    const scene = new BABYLON.Scene(engine);
    // Creates and positions a free camera
    const camera = new BABYLON.FreeCamera('camera1', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5, -10), scene);
    // Targets the camera to scene origin
    camera.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero());
    // This attaches the camera to the canvas
    camera.attachControl(canvas, true);
    // Creates a light, aiming 0,1,0 - to the sky
    const light = new BABYLON.HemisphericLight('light', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), scene);
    // Dim the light a small amount - 0 to 1
    light.intensity = 0.7;
    // Built-in 'sphere' shape.
    const sphere = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateSphere('sphere', { diameter: 2, segments: 32 }, scene);
    // Move the sphere upward 1/2 its height
    sphere.position.y = 1;
    // Built-in 'ground' shape.
    const ground = BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateGround('ground', { width: 6, height: 6 }, scene);
    return scene;
};
const scene = createScene(); //Call the createScene function
// Register a render loop to repeatedly render the scene
engine.runRenderLoop(function () {
    scene.render();
});
// Watch for browser/canvas resize events
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    engine.resize();
});
```

`webpack.config.js`:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    externals: {
        babylonjs: 'BABYLON',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
        }),
    ],
};
```

`package.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack",
        "start": "http-server ./dist"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
        "http-server": "^14.1.1",
        "webpack": "^5.80.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

Build logs:

```
> webpack

asset main.js 592 bytes [emitted] [minimized] (name: main)
asset index.html 392 bytes [emitted]
./src/index.js 1.36 KiB [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.88.2 compiled successfully in 251 ms
```

**Output**

`dist/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta
            http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"
            content="IE=edge"
        />
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"
        />
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://preview.babylonjs.com/babylon.js?t=1682926053948"></script>
        <script
            defer="defer"
            src="main.js"
        ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="renderCanvas"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

`dist/main.js`:

```js
(() => {
    const e = document.getElementById('renderCanvas'),
        n = new BABYLON.Engine(e, !0),
        r = (function () {
            const r = new BABYLON.Scene(n),
                t = new BABYLON.FreeCamera('camera1', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 5, -10), r);
            return (
                t.setTarget(BABYLON.Vector3.Zero()),
                t.attachControl(e, !0),
                (new BABYLON.HemisphericLight('light', new BABYLON.Vector3(0, 1, 0), r).intensity = 0.7),
                (BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateSphere('sphere', { diameter: 2, segments: 32 }, r).position.y = 1),
                BABYLON.MeshBuilder.CreateGround('ground', { width: 6, height: 6 }, r),
                r
            );
        })();
    n.runRenderLoop(function () {
        r.render();
    }),
        window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
            n.resize();
        });
})();
```

As you can see, the babylon.js will not be bundled.

Start an HTTP server to serve the `dist/index.html` using the `http-server` package.

[image]